# Function not looping properly for Arduino with NeoPixels

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm animating/lighting a sign using an Arduino + NeoPixels for Halloween at my place of work. One of my two functions (a slow, spreading, red glow) works fine. The other - a slowing heartbeat - never slows down and seems stuck in an infinite loop.

Here's the full, relevant code:

```
void loop() {
    // HeartBeat Test
   for(int bpm=60;bpm >= 0;bpm=bpm-3) {
       systolicUp(bpm);
       systolicDown(bpm);
       diastolicUp(bpm);
       diastolicDown(bpm);
       restBeat(bpm);
   }
}


void systolicUp(int i) {
    uint16_t beatSeconds, firstPulse, firstIncrement, j, k;
    beatSeconds =  60000/i;
    firstPulse = beatSeconds * 0.6;
    firstIncrement = firstPulse/170;
    for(j=0; j <= 255; j=j+3) {
        uint32_t redShade = strip.Color(j, 0, 0);
        for (k=0; k<strip.numPixels(); k++) {
            strip.setPixelColor(k, redShade);
        }
        strip.show();
        delay(firstIncrement);
    }
}

void systolicDown(int i) {
    uint16_t beatSeconds, firstPulse, firstIncrement, j, k;
    beatSeconds =  60000/i;
    firstPulse = beatSeconds * 0.6;
    firstIncrement = firstPulse/170;
    for(j=255; j >= 0; j=j-3) {
        uint32_t redShade = strip.Color(j, 0, 0);
        for (k=0; k<strip.numPixels(); k++) {
            strip.setPixelColor(k, redShade);
        }
        strip.show();
        delay(firstIncrement);
    }
}

void diastolicUp(int i) {
    uint16_t beatSeconds, secondPulse, secondIncrement, j, k;
    beatSeconds =  60000/i;
    secondPulse = beatSeconds * 0.3;
    secondIncrement = secondPulse/170;
    for(j=0; j <= 255; j=j+3) {
        uint32_t redShade = strip.Color(j, 0, 0);
        for (k=0; k<strip.numPixels(); k++) {
            strip.setPixelColor(k, redShade);
        }
        strip.show();
        delay(secondIncrement);
    }
}

void diastolicDown(int i) {
    beatSeconds =  60000/i;
    uint16_t beatSeconds, secondPulse, secondIncrement, j, k;
    secondPulse = beatSeconds * 0.3;
    secondIncrement = secondPulse/170;
    for(j=255; j >= 0; j=j-3) {
        uint32_t redShade = strip.Color(j, 0, 0);
        for (k=0; k<strip.numPixels(); k++) {
            strip.setPixelColor(k, redShade);
        }
        strip.show();
        delay(secondIncrement);
    }
}

void restBeat(int i) {
    uint16_t beatSeconds, rest, g;
    beatSeconds =  60000/i;
    rest = beatSeconds * 0.1;
    for (g=0; g<strip.numPixels(); g++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(g, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(rest);
}
```

By the math, I should be handing over a certain number of beats-per-minute, the number of seconds-per-beat is calculated, the light pulses once over 60% of that, pulses again over 30%, and then is silent for 10%. This should happen 20 times, with each beat getting slower progressively until it stops completely.

Instead, I'm getting steady once-per-second blinking.

I'm certain it'll end up being something that I've totally overlooked, or missed in the NeoPixel documentation. But, as I'm either overlooking or have totally missed it, help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void diastolicDown(int i) {
    beatSeconds =  60000/i;
    uint16_t beatSeconds, secondPulse, secondIncrement, j, k;`

Here you're trying to assign a value to `beatSeconds` before its declaration.

Comment: I'll test that out momentarily. I think that might be a formatting-for-SO typo, as it compiles cleanly and wouldn't if I tried to assign an undeclared variable.

Comment: That was part of the problem. The *bigger* problem was the `uint16_t` being used for `beatSeconds` or the pulses at all, as the large values being calculated caused issues. I swapped to plain `int` declarations, and it began working immediately.